# devise_security_extension :install command not working

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

rails 4.2.1.rc4, devise 3.5.1, devise uid 0.1.1, devise_security_extension 0.9.2

the generator finishes with "insert config/initializers/devise.rb" and installs the locale files but, there is no new information added to devise.rb and there is no devise_security_extensions.rb file.

is there a fix? or manual install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the :install command is actually working and installing the engine. I inserted the devise_security_extension.rb code into devise.rb and configured how I wanted it and it is working.

What I have found is that if you have modified your devise.rb file and then try to install devise_security_extension it will not inject its code.

Answer (score 0):

After you generates `rails generate devise_security_extension:install`, it will creates some security inputs in devise.rb file -

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  # ==> Security Extension
  # Configure security extension for devise

  # Should the password expire (e.g 3.months)
  # config.expire_password_after = 3.months

  # Need 1 char of A-Z, a-z and 0-9
  # config.password_regex = /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])/

  # How often save old passwords in archive
  # config.password_archiving_count = 5

  # Deny old password (true, false, count)
  # config.deny_old_passwords = true

  # captcha integration for recover form
  # config.captcha_for_recover = true

  # captcha integration for sign up form
  # config.captcha_for_sign_up = true

  # captcha integration for sign in form
  # config.captcha_for_sign_in = true

  # captcha integration for unlock form
  # config.captcha_for_unlock = true

  # security_question integration for recover form
  # this automatically enables captchas (captcha_for_recover, as fallback)
  # config.security_question_for_recover = false

  # security_question integration for unlock form
  # this automatically enables captchas (captcha_for_unlock, as fallback)
  # config.security_question_for_unlock = false

  # security_question integration for confirmation form
  # this automatically enables captchas (captcha_for_confirmation, as fallback)
  # config.security_question_for_confirmation = false

  # ==> Configuration for :expirable
  # Time period for account expiry from last_activity_at
  # config.expire_after = 90.days
end
```

More security changes, Please see https://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension

Comment: as i said in my post **there is no new information added to devise.rb**

Comment: Have you ran this `rails generate devise_security_extension:install`

Comment: again, as stated in the post **the generator finishes with "insert config/initializers/devise.rb" and installs the locale files**

Comment: So, there is new Configure security extension in devise.rb or not ?

Comment: NO! AS STATED IN THE POST!

Comment: Can you please post devise.rb file here in your question.

Comment: No, it's too long to post as per Stackoverflow. It is the same file from a default devise install with my changes applied.